# How to make Cloud Deploy releases idempotent

Tags: kubernetes, skaffold, google-cloud-deploy

Currently, every time I deploy a new release using Cloud Deploy, my pods are restarted even if they don't have any changes. After some researching, I realized that pods are recreated because of `skaffold.dev/run-id` label [is updated on every release](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/pull/2752). In [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/issues/2745#issuecomment-986870415), there's a workaround to solve the problem at Skaffold level, which is basically to set that label to any fixed value through environment variable `SKAFFOLD_LABEL`, so I did something like:

```bash
export SKAFFOLD_LABEL="skaffold.dev/run-id=fixed"
gcloud deploy releases create $RELEASE_NAME \
    --delivery-pipeline=$DELIVERY_PIPELINE_NAME \
    --region=$LOCATION
```

However, this workaround doesn't seem to work with Cloud Deploy. How should I configure this Skaffold label to make it work using Cloud Deploy, or make Cloud deploy releases idempotent?